# Is it possible to convert the parametric curve defined by $x = t^3 - 3t$ and $y = t^2 - 4$ to an implicit function?

Tags: parametric

Is it possible to convert the parametric curve defined by $$x = t^3 - 3t \text{ and } y = t^2 - 4$$ 
to an implicit function?

Comment: It *is* a plane curve. Are you asking if it's possible to express it as $y=f(x)$?

Comment: @rogerl No, it does not necesserily have to be expressible as an explicit function. An implicit function would be just fine. I just want to eliminate the $t$ and express the curve only in the varibles $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it in a more user friendly cartesian form, you can start with $$\frac xt=t^2-3=y+1$$
So $$t=\frac{x}{y+1}$$
$$\implies y=\frac{x^2}{(y+1)^2}-4$$
$$\implies x^2=(y+4)(y+1)^2$$

Comment: Should get $t = \dfrac{x}{y + 1}$

Comment: Also https://www.desmos.com/calculator/osnjbnkxni  and https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zi2n1d6rez

Comment: $t^2-3=t^2-4+1=y \,\mathbf\, + 1$

Comment: @DanielV   yes thanks for that

Answer (score 3):

$x^2 = t^6 - 6t^4+9t^2$, and $t^2 = y+4$; substituting gives
$$x^2 = (y+4)^3 - 6(y+4)^2 + 9(y+4) = (y+4)(y+1)^2.$$

Answer (score 3):

$x/t = y + 1$, hence $x^2 / t^2 = (y + 1)^2$, hence
$$
\frac{x^2}{y + 4} = (y + 1)^2
$$
However! This is not completely equivalent form ...

Answer (score 0):

If you mean can $y$ be expressed explicitly in term of $x$ or vice versa no, but this is an attempt:
$$y=t^2-4$$
$$t=\pm\sqrt{y+4}$$
$$x=t^3-3t=\pm(y+4)^{3/2}\mp3\sqrt{y+4}$$